# Viewmodel from two aggregate root

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, aggregateroot

I have two aggregate root :

**Event :**

---

Id  -  name  -   title - categoryId

**Category :**

---

Id  -   CategoryName

These model are separate aggregate roots in my project.and i have a viewmodel from these models(asp.net mvc) :

**EventViewModel:**

---

Id  - name  - title - CategoryId - CategoryName

***Problem :***
because these are separate aggregate root then i cant't use navigation property . and  reference by id(categoryId).so what is best solution for map viewmodel?

- join query in entityframework?
- navigation property?
- change view model by combine 2 models and map them separely(coupling)?

thanks,

Comment: I guess you can join `ID` in Category and `CategoryID` in Event.

Comment: Is this common problem ? or it is for my design . I searched too much but can't find a nice solution.Is join between two aggregate root is best practice?

Comment: The best practice is to use navigational properties to get to the related items. That's a very simple and common use case.

Comment: Yes , but these models are in separate aggregate root.and should reference by id .these aren't parent and child in one aggregate.Whether I'm wrong?